# My node.title differs from the title field in the database

Tags: database, nodes

I have a wierd problem i can't seem to get a solution to. I have a Drupal 7 website with more then 10000 nodes. And i recently discovered that 2000 of them have exactly the same typo in the title. So I did an update on the database fixing the node.title field. But for some reason the title in the Drupal website is not updated. When i save the node in drupal the database get's updated, so the other way around works. I deleted all the cache and those kind of things. Still the same problem. What else can I check?

Comment: Are you using revisions? If so, look at the database field `node_revision.title`

Comment: Yes that's the case :) I thought about the revisions but was looking for a field_revision_title like the field_revision_body. Thanks :)